# Understanding recursive method for printing binary tree

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm stepping through the code [from this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DW5ScDBH-E) YouTube tutorial and can't make much sense of the recursive Print function:

```
    public void Print(Node N, ref string s)
    {
        if (N == null) { N = top; }
        if (N.left != null)
        {
            Print(N.left, ref s);
            s = s + N.value.ToString().PadLeft(3);
        }
        else
        {
            s = s + N.value.ToString().PadLeft(3);
        }
        if (N.right != null)
        {
            Print(N.right, ref s);
        }
    }
```

I'm using the following unsorted array to populate the tree:

`int[] unsortedArray = new int[] {5, 17, 11, 24, 3, 18, 9};`

I understand that in through the first pass of the `Print` method, the `top` value is equal to 5. The program then drops into the first condition and executes this recursive call

```
Print(N.left, ref s);
```

Since the input parameter `Node N` is now the left node of the root, which happens to be the lowest value in the tree, it's left node is `null` and therefore the program drops into the `else` condition below

```
else
{
     `s = s + N.value.ToString().PadLeft(3);    
}
```

Where I'm lost is what happens next. To me, it seems that, since this node contains no right leaf, the program would evaluate the `if(N.right !=null)` condition and then exit the `Print` method.

Instead, the code evaluates the `if`, then jumps to the `Print(N.left, ref s);` line in the first condition:

```
        if (N.left != null)
        {
            Print(N.left, ref s);
            s = s + N.value.ToString().PadLeft(3);
        }
```

First time really delving into recursion. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: you may perhaps jump into stack frames (call stack) along with the recursion. That will bring an additional insight into the depth of the recursion and probably highlight why it continues with `N.left` after `N.right` is null or other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing out this post the answer became pretty clear. The reason the program jumps back to this line

`Print(N.left, ref s);`

is that was where the recursive call originated. Once the input parameter `Node N` no longer contains a right node the program exits that iteration of the method. Someone might be able to explain this better, so I'll leave the post up without a selected answer for a bit.